# google drive api to upload all pdfs to google drive

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client, pydrive

I am using the pydrive to upload pdf files to my google drive folder. I am wanting to send all `*pdf` files in a local folder at once with this code but not sure where to go from here? Should I use `glob`? If so I would like to see an example, please.

working code that sends 1 file to the designated google drive folder:

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(g_login)

folder_id = 'google_drive_id_goes_here'
f = drive.CreateFile({'title': 'testing_pdf',
                      'mimeType': 'application/pdf',
                      'parents': [{'kind': 'drive#fileLink', 'id':folder_id}]})
f.SetContentFile('/Users/Documents/python/google_drive/testing.pdf')
f.Upload()
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant upload files at once.  Create file with the API is a single thing and pydrive as no mechanism for [uploading](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/filemanagement.html#upload-a-new-file) more then one .

Your going to have to put this in a loop and upload each file as you go.

```
import os
directory = 'the/directory/you/want/to/use'

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        f = open(filename)
        lines = f.read()
        print (lines[10])
        continue
    else:
    continue
```

Comment: got DalmTo - will try something using the loop. appreciate the hint.